# Pathクラスのresolveメソッド

Tags: java, windows

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\\gold\\.");
        p1 = p1.resolve("dir1");
        Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\gold");
        p2 = p2.resolve("\\dir2");
        System.out.print(p1 + " : ");
        System.out.print(p2);
    }
}
```

変数p2は"C:\dir2"に出力されますが、resolveメソッドの引数である

"\dir2"は絶対パスではありません。

私の考えでは変数p2の出力結果は"C:\gold\dir2"のはずですが、私の認識になにが

間違えているのか教えてください。

Answer (score 3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#paths

の記載によると、

- `\\`(2つのバックスラッシュ)ではじまるもの(UNCパス)
- `C:\`、`d:\`など、ドライブレターとスラッシュではじまるもの
- `\`(一つのバックスラッシュではじまる)もの

が、絶対パスですので、`\dir2`は絶対パスです。

---

以下原文

> Fully Qualified vs. Relative Paths
>
> For Windows API functions that manipulate files, file names can often be relative to the current directory, while some APIs require a fully qualified path. A file name is relative to the current directory if it does not begin with one of the following:
>
> - A UNC name of any format, which always start with two backslash characters ("\\"). For more information, see the next section.
> - A disk designator with a backslash, for example "C:\" or "d:\".
> - A single backslash, for example, "\directory" or "\file.txt". This is also referred to as an absolute path.